# How does __declspec(dllimport) on a class affect the class's functions?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, inline, dllimport

The following MCVE gives a warning, using mingw-w64 4.9.2:

```
struct __declspec(dllimport) S
{
    int   foo() { return func(); }
    int   func();
    void  other_func();
};

inline int S::func() { return 1000; }

int main() {}
```

The warning is:

```
dt.cc:9:5: warning: 'int S::func()' redeclared without dllimport attribute
           after being referenced with dll linkage
inline int S::func() { return 1000; }
    ^
```

My question is: what is the problem being reported exactly, and should I do anything about it (e.g. file a bug report)?

The warning goes away if I change `int func();` to `inline int func();` -- not sure what the significance of this is.

*Background:* This pattern occurs in many places in the C++ library called POCO. The class has some functions whose bodies are in a DLL (e.g. `other_func` here) and some functions whose bodies occur in the header file (e.g. `func` here).

Comment: I would guess that as an `inline` function it's not exported by the DLL.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf so are you saying I should just try to disable this warning or what?

Comment: I feel that such warnings must be there for some reason. So if I controlled the code I would either define the function in the class definition (or at the least declare it `inline` there), thus presumably not exporting it, or else replace the `inline` definition with a proper in the implementation file, for DLL export. Since you're not controlling the code but it's a widely used library perhaps just disable the warning for now, *and* report the issue. However, I don't see a warning name. How does one disable an unnamed g++ warning?

Comment: Yeah I was wondering the same thing.  One thing I'm not clear on (hence the question title) is whether the declspec in the class definition "propagates", i.e. do `foo`, `func` and `other_func` behave as if they also were `__declspec(dllimport)`, or does that explicitly have to be written into each function's declaration?  The warning suggests that `func()` is treated as being `dllimport` up until the point where its definition appears  (if the `foo` function is removed, the error goes away).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf actually I have found a duplicate